# TypeScript error TS5014: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

I am trying to compile a .ts to .js

I have `tsconfig.json` as below

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outFile": "build/test.js"
},
"exclude": [
    "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

below is my `package.json`

```
{
    "name": "test",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
    },
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "dependencies": {
        "tsc": "^1.20150623.0",
        "typescript": "^2.4.2"
    }
}
```

and the auto generated `tasks.json` looks like below

```
{
// See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
// for the documentation about the tasks.json format
"version": "2.0.0",
"tasks": [
    {
        "type": "typescript",
        "tsconfig": "tsconfig.json",
        "problemMatcher": [
            "$tsc"
        ],
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        }
    }]
}
```

When I try to run the build task, I am getting the below error

```
Executing task: <myprojloc>\node_modules\.bin\tsc.cmd  -p "<myprojloc>\tsconfig.json" <

error TS5014: Failed to parse file '<myprojloc>/tsconfig.json/tsconfig.json': Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0.

Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
```

What I am doing wrong? Please, note I have added the versions in `package.json`

Comment: Maybe you have BOM [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark] at the beginning of the file.

Comment: i saved that file without BOM also. still same @Felix

Comment: also added "emitBOM": false in tsconfig.json. no difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying something from this [link](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks), I re-write the tasks.json as below and it now worked. Seems the command has some problem previously

```
{
// See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
// for the documentation about the tasks.json format
"version": "2.0.0",
"tasks": [
    {
        "taskName": "compile",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "tsc -p tsconfig.json",
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        },
        "problemMatcher": []
    }
]
}
```

Answer (score 61):

I would like to put in that you also see this error when you forgot to add 'typescript' as a dependency.

```
npm install typescript
```

should fix that.

Note that this dependency **is** present in the package.json in the question.

Comment: This solved my issue. Though I was pretty sure I've installed typescript before.

Comment: funny how error message says it can't parse JSON string, but nothing about TypeScript missing 

Answer (score 8):

If you look at the error message carefully, you can see the reason for the failure.  The command line that was formed to run `tsc` is looking at the wrong directory.  It was looking at `<myprojloc>/tsconfig.json/` instead of `<myprojloc>/`.  See how tsconfig.json is repeated twice in the error?

`error TS5014: Failed to parse file '<myprojloc>/tsconfig.json/tsconfig.json': Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0.`

Running `npm install typescript --save-dev` worked for me, but I can see how editing the task and specifying the `command` to look in the right directory for tsconfig.json would solve the problem too.

Comment: I don't know what's wrong but when having typescript in dependency instead of devDepnedency was leading to the error above.

Comment: Triple check path for JS file then running `npm install typescript --save-dev` has fixed the issue, thanks. For some reason the output path was reverted to default. **Cannot find module with TSC.**

Comment: I ran into this (with the double `tsconfig.json`) because I was accidentally using my globally-installed `tsc` rather than my local one... because I forgot to stick `yarn` at the beginning of my command (`tsc blah blah` rather than `yarn tsc blah blah`). ‍♀️

Answer (score 4):

There could be a bunch of things that can go wrong when saving a file that would prevent correct parsing. I usually elect to not deal with it by renaming the file to `tsconfig.json.backup` or something, then invoking `tsc --init` to generate a known good file. You can then transfer your specific configuration into the newly generated `tsconfig.json` file, uncommenting the parts you care about.

If it persists after that, it could be an actual bug in the TypeScript version you're on.

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this issue while using **Git Bash** as VS Code's default shell. Switch the default shell to **Command Prompt**, run `npm install typescript` for posterity, and build again.

I am using the "default" tsc build task:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
      {
        "type": "typescript",
        "tsconfig": "tsconfig.json",
        "problemMatcher": ["$tsc"],
        "group": {
          "kind": "build",
          "isDefault": true
        }
      }
    ]
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

For everyone that is facing that error, try to put the whole file in one line.
After that, run again the command that you are trying and go to the exact char  that the error is pointing. For example:
`tsconfig.json: Unexpected token } in JSON at position 1040`
In that position you will probably find your issue. Maybe a comma or a comment..

Answer (score 0):

For my case, I had typescript but the pbm was my `tsconfig.json` got some trailling comma `,` on one last item. Remove trailling commas in that file

[image]

Some related thread: https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/1462#issuecomment-524878788

Answer (score 0):

You can also check the JSON file encoding. In my case, I was getting this error because the encoding was UTF-16 LE. I changed it to UTF-8 and it worked.

Answer (score -1):

No need to uninstall tsc, just use `npm install typescript` at the project root level